# visual studio - "tag" some code with a test

Tags: visual-studio, testing

I'm making sure all my code has test coverage by just associating some code (a method, or maybe an if/else branch) with a unique id, and then associating some tests with that same unique id, but its all just commented out guid strings. Is there a better way at specifically managing tests and the code snippets they relate to?

Answer (score 0):

I added this as an enhancement request for NYC, seems like its been endorsed, hopefully it will be implemented

https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/597